# LINUX: List all directories, push into a bash array

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, scripting

Here's the end result I am trying to:

I have over 15 users of an cloned instance of my application, sometimes I need to update files (they pretty much all stay the same--everything is dynamic. This is for updates/new features). I wrote a pretty simple bash script that I had to manually put each user from /home/ into the array. But I need this to scale.

How can I take a directory listing (something like a LS command) feed ONLY DIRECTORY names into then a bash array. Likely i'll want this command in the bash file though, because I'll want it to grab all users in the /home/ directory, push into the array (eg: webUsers( adam john jack )

Here's a snapshot of what my current script looks like (non-dynamic user listing)

```
webUsers( adam john jack )

for i in "${webUsers[@]}"
do 
 cp /home/mainSource/public_html/templates/_top.tpl /home/$i/public_html/templates
done
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
webUsers=(/home/*/)
```

and the contents will look like:

```
$ declare -p webUsers
declare -a webUsers='([0]="/home/adam/" [1]="/home/jack/" [2]="/home/john")'
$ echo ${webUsers[1]}
/home/jack/
```

Or, if you don't want the parent directory:

```
pushd /home
webUsers=(*/)
popd
```

and you'll get:

```
$ declare -p webUsers
declare -a webUsers='([0]="adam/" [1]="jack/" [2]="john")'
$ echo ${webUsers[1]}
jack/
```

Answer (score 3):

The following script will loop over all users with directories in `/home`. It will also unconditionally try to create the `/public_html/templates` directory. If it doesn't yet exist, it will get created. If it *does* exist, this command does essentially nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home
userarr=( */ );

for user in "${userarr[@]%*/}"; do
   mkdir -p "/home/${user}/public_html/templates"
   cp "/home/mainSource/public_html/templates/_top.tpl /home/${user}/public_html/templates"
done
```

Comment: is there a way to check to see if my "public_html/templates" directory exists. There maybe a few cases where they do not, eg my user.

Comment: @user answer updated to handle the `public_html/templates` folder

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to make a link to the source directory, and then you can just update it in one place.

Just set up each users directory so that the common files are all pulled from a directory called common_files (or whatever you like), and then run this command in each home directory:

```
ln -s /location/of/files/they/need common_files
```

update /location/of/files/they/need and it automatically propagates.

Answer (score 0):

With bash you can actually make this pretty short and simple. To list the current directory and store it into an array:

```
ls . | readarray i
```

or

`ls . | bash -c 'readarray i'`

To use the data:

`ls . | bash -c 'readarray i && for j in ${i[*]}; do <-command->; done'`